# How can I remove "thebibliography" from the Table of Contents (TOC)?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, bibliographies

I want to use a manual Bibliography but I need it as a subsection. In order to do this I did:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\section{My Section}

\subsection{References}

\begingroup

\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}%

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\em Readings compiled for History
  21.479.}  1991.

\end{thebibliography}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

By doing this, I am hiding the default "References" section title and replacing it with my manual `\subsection{References}` title. This works great, but the problem I am having right now is that the default "References" title shows up on my Table of Contents when I use `\tableofcontents`. How can I remove the default title (the one created by `\begin{thebibliography}{}`) from my Table of Contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using any packages, you can just remove the `\addcontentsline` macro's functionality before calling `\subsection{References}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{My Section}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}% Remove functionality of \addcontentsline
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}% Remove functionality of \section
\subsection{References}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
  \bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\em Readings compiled for History
    21.479.}  1991.
\end{thebibliography}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`tocvsec2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocvsec2) package to change the tocdepth to `1` just before the subsection (you can restore the value after the bibliography, if needed). I also used the `etoolbox` package to patch `\thebibliography` and suppress the default title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{My Section}

\settocdepth{section}
\subsection{References}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\em Readings compiled for History
  21.479.}  1991.
\end{thebibliography}
%\settocdepth{subsection}% in case you need this

\end{document}
```

[image]