# Using multiple bibliography sections in scrreprt

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, scrreprt

I am using `scrreprt` package and trying to make two sections titled 'References' and 'Publication List'. See a screenshot of desired output-

[image: a screenshot of desired output]

Please see below MWE. Please note that this is a workaround and I want to improve it-

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,fontsize=12pt,DIV=calc,BCOR=0mm,Ipagesize=auto,draft=false]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% for the top margin in publication section
\newcommand{\cuttop}{-0.5in}

\begin{document}
% \titlepage % (omitted to keep it short)
\tableofcontents
% \listoffigures % (omitted to keep it short)
\clearpage % start a new page

\chapter{My Chapter}
All of these citations~\cite{einstein05,goossens93,knuthwebsite} are kept inside references.bib file.
\lipsum[2-4]  % sample text

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references,publications}

\clearpage % start a new page
\section*{\Huge Publication List}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Publication List}
\begingroup
% src: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114345/49520
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}
\let\clearpage\relax

\vspace*{\cuttop}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\Large Journal Papers}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
  \bibitem{ahu61}
  Kenneth~J. Arrow, Leonid Hurwicz, and Hirofumi Uzawa.
  \newblock Constraint qualifications in maximization problems.
  \newblock {\em Naval Research Logistics Quarterly}, 8:175--191, 1961.
\end{thebibliography}

\vspace*{\cuttop}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\Large Conference Papers}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
  \bibitem{ah2006}
  Gagan Aggarwal and Jason~D. Hartline.
  \newblock Knapsack auctions.
  \newblock In {\em Proceedings of the 17th Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete
  Algorithms}, pages 1083--1092, New York, 2006. Association for Computing
  Machinery.
\end{thebibliography}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

I plan to have two `.bib` files such as `references.bib` and `publications.bib`. This is what I am trying to execute-

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,fontsize=12pt,DIV=calc,BCOR=0mm,Ipagesize=auto,draft=false]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% for the top margin in publication section
\newcommand{\cuttop}{-0.5in}

\begin{document}
% \titlepage % (omitted to keep it short)
\tableofcontents
% \listoffigures % (omitted to keep it short)
\clearpage % start a new page

\chapter{My Chapter}
All of these citations~\cite{einstein05,goossens93,knuthwebsite} are kept inside references.bib file.
\lipsum[2-4]  % sample text

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references,publications}

\clearpage % start a new page
\section*{\Huge Publication List}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Publication List}
\begingroup
% src: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114345/49520
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}
\let\clearpage\relax

\vspace*{\cuttop}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\Large Journal Papers}
\nocite{ahu61}

\vspace*{\cuttop}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\Large Conference Papers}
\nocite{ah2006}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

The above code doesn't produce expected results (see expected results [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNyot.jpg)).

The `references.bib` file is shown below.

```
@article{einstein05,
    author  = {Albert Einstein},
    title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper. (German) [On the electrodynamics of moving bodies]}},
    journal = {Annalen der Physik},
    volume  = {322},
    number  = {10},
    pages   = {891--921},
    year    = {1905},
    DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004}
}

@book{goossens93,
    author    = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
    title     = {{The \LaTeX\ Companion}},
    year      = {1993},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    address   = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author = {Donald Knuth},
    title  = {{Knuth: Computers and Typesetting}},
    url    = {http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html}
}
```

The `publications.bib` file is shown below.

```
@article{ahu61,
   author  = {Arrow, Kenneth J. and Leonid Hurwicz and Hirofumi Uzawa},
   title   = {Constraint qualifications in maximization problems},
   journal = {Naval Research Logistics Quarterly},
   volume  = {8},
   year    = 1961,
   pages   = {175-191}
}

@inproceedings{ah2006,
   author    = {Aggarwal, Gagan and Hartline, Jason D.},
   year      = {2006},
   title     = {Knapsack auctions},
   booktitle = {Proceedings of the 17th Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms},
   pages     = {1083-1092},
   publisher = {Association for Computing Machinery},
   address   = {New York}
}
```

**I am looking for suggestions to improve the MWE posted at the beginning of this question.**

### Update

As per the suggestion from [Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/37907/johannes-b), I switched to `biblatex` with `biber` backend. Please see the updated code below-

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,fontsize=12pt,DIV=calc,BCOR=0mm,Ipagesize=auto,draft=false]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% for the top margin in publication section
\newcommand{\cutmargin}{-0.5in}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}

\begin{document}
% \titlepage % (omitted to keep it short)
\tableofcontents
% \listoffigures % (omitted to keep it short)
\clearpage % start a new page

\chapter{My Chapter}
All of these citations~\cite{einstein05,goossens93,knuthwebsite} are kept inside references.bib file.
\lipsum[2-4]  % sample text

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\printbibliography

\clearpage % start a new page
\section*{\Huge Publication List}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Publication List}
\begingroup
% src: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114345/49520
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}
\let\clearpage\relax

\vspace*{\cutmargin}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\Large Journal Papers}
\nocite{ahu61}

\vspace*{\cutmargin}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\Large Conference Papers}
\nocite{ah2006}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Please see the generated output file below (a comparison has been shown here)-

[image]

Following are the limitation (and needs to be solved)-

- Page 1: 'References' are not a part of table of content anymore. How to add it?
- Page 3: 'References' are containing publications too. Please note that the first two references are not used in `\cite` command. I want the 'References' to contain only `\cite` items.
- Page 4: 'Publication List' page is empty. How to get it back?

## Second Update

Check answer below.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't use the old approach. Use the modern way with biblatex and biber. Please have a look at https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: @Johannes_B: Thank you very much. Please see the updated question. I have appended the latest progress in the question and mentioned your name.

Comment: Have you read the sections about splitting by entry type and topic in the wikibook? Keywords should be exactly what you are looking for. With \printbibliography, you can also add the toc entry.

Comment: After spending so much time, I realized that `heading=bibintoc` isn't working in my PC but working in overleaf. I am using `biber version: 2.11` and `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)`. Any idea, please?

Comment: Right now? No. I don't have a working PC. Please update the question, it will go back to the of questions and more people will see it. Please also include the biblatex tag, so moewe will have a higher chance to see your question.

Comment: Since `heading=bibintoc` is a different issue, I am creating a separate question. Please have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/538328/49520).

Comment: @Johannes_B: I did it. Please see the second update, which is appended to the question. What do you think? Is it possible to improve the following `\section*{\Huge Publication List}` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Publication List}`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved through a discussion in comments

Comment: @BambOo : Yes, the question was solved through a discussion. I have added the answer below as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: @bamboo off-topic as solved in comments is for questions asking what's wrong with \tableofcotnets. This question is perfectly on topic, searching for a suitable duplicate would have been better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to finish it with the suggestions given by [Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/37907/johannes-b). Below is the MWE-

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,fontsize=12pt,DIV=calc,BCOR=0mm,Ipagesize=auto,draft=false]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=biber,refsection=section,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{My Chapter}
All of these citations~\cite{einstein05,goossens93,knuthwebsite} are kept inside references.bib file.

\clearpage
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]

\clearpage
\addchap{Publication List}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,resetnumbers=true,keyword={journal},title={Journal Papers}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,resetnumbers=true,keyword={conference},title={Conference Papers}]
\end{document}
```