# heading=bibintoc is working in Overleaf but not in my PC

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, pdftex, biber, overleaf

I am facing an unusual problem. I noticed that `heading=bibintoc` is working in Overleaf but not on my PC. See MWE below-

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{einstein05,
    author  = {Albert Einstein},
    title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper. (German) [On the electrodynamics of moving bodies]}},
    journal = {Annalen der Physik},
    volume  = {322},
    number  = {10},
    pages   = {891--921},
    year    = {1905},
    DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004}
}

@book{goossens93,
    author    = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
    title     = {{The \LaTeX\ Companion}},
    year      = {1993},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    address   = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author = {Donald Knuth},
    title  = {{Knuth: Computers and Typesetting}},
    url    = {http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\chapter{My Chapter}
All of these citations~\cite{einstein05,goossens93,knuthwebsite} are kept inside references.bib file.
\lipsum[2-4]

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
\end{document}
```

Please see the TOC generated by my PC (compared with Overleaf)-

[image]

Clearly, we can see that 'References' are not added to ToC when complied in my PC. Below is the information on my PC-

```
ravi@home:~$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
kpathsea version 6.3.0
Copyright 2018 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.00

ravi@home:~$ biber --version
biber version: 2.11

ravi@home:~$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.6 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"

ravi@home:~$ uname -a
Linux home 4.4.0-148-generic #174~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 9 08:17:37 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Below is the sequence of commands, I am executing to compile the file-

1. pdflatex main.tex
2. biber main
3. pdflatex main.tex

PS: I am also sharing the Overleaf project, which can be edited. Please see [here](https://www.overleaf.com/1261914882cwxmwprtvnfg).

Comment: The MWE produces the expected output on my fully updated MikTeX. TeX live 2018 quite is outdated now (TeX live 2020 was just released). The compatibility between `biblatex` and KOMA-Script classes was improved some time ago (I don't quite remember when it was), so I can only presume your system doesn't have that patch yet. Does `\defbibheading{bibintoc}[\bibname]{\addchap{#1}}` in the preamble help?

Comment: Mhhh, I was thinking about https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/627, but a bit of digging reveals that `\defbibheading{bibintoc}` has contained `\addchap` (which is the relevant bit) since at least 2016 (there were a few changes to the running heads, but nothing for the ToC), so I'm not sure is relevant...

Comment: @moewe: Thank you very much. I added `\defbibheading{bibintoc}[\bibname]{\addchap{#1}}` just after `\addbibresource{references.bib}`  and before `\begin{document}`. But no luck!

Comment: Do you get an entry in the ToC if you say `\addchap{Foo}` somewhere in your document, say before `\printbibliography`? Just to double check: Does `biblatex` produce any bibliography at all? Do you see the citations as expected? (Are there any warnings in the `.log` file?)

Comment: Oh yes! I added `\addchap{Foo}` before `printbibliography` and I could see `Foo` in ToC. Also, a blank page with title Foo has been added before `References`

Comment: Does `biblatex` produce a bibliography?

Comment: @moewe: Yes. I can see `References` on the last page. The only problem is that I cant see Toc for `References`.

Comment: In your screenshots it seems that Overleaf does not show the References in the TOC but your local PC does show them, but in your question you say it is the other way around, so which is it?

Comment: I am so sorry. The screenshot should be reversed. I am going to correct it now. I can see references being added to ToC when I use overleaf.

Comment: @Marijn: Corrected now. I am really sorry for the inconvenience. Please have a look again.

Comment: @moewe and Marijn: Please see shared overleaf project [here](https://www.overleaf.com/1261914882cwxmwprtvnfg). Please note that the Overleaf project is working fine but not my local texlive.

Comment: I got it. `pdflatex` must be executed twice after `biber` !!! Thank you very much.

Comment: Ugh, of course. Please write up an answer that you can accept and don't answer the question in the question.

Comment: @moewe: Thank you very much. I followed your suggestion. Please see below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pdflatex` must be executed twice after `biber`. Below is the **correct** sequence of commands to compile the file-

1. pdflatex main.tex
2. biber main
3. pdflatex main.tex
4. pdflatex main.tex